# Customizing the justification of rows in a table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to justify the first row cells in center and the other rows on the left. So, I write this code

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

Table \ref{wrk-desc} briefly
\begin{table}[]
\caption{}
\label{prt-desc}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{Suite} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \textbf{Workload} \\ 
\hline
Item1        & program1, program2, ...       \\ 
\hline
Item1        & program10, program11, ...       \\
\hline
Item1        & program20, program21, ...       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, the output is not correct.

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works using the `thead` command from `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

Table \ref{wrk-desc} briefly
\begin{table}[]
\caption{}\label{wrk-desc}
\label{prt-desc}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
    \thead{\bfseries Suite} & \thead{\bfseries Workload} \\
\hline
Item1 & program1, program2, ... \\
\hline
Item1 & program10, program11, ... \\
\hline
Item1 & program20, program21, ... \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why table formatting is so much tricky in tex :)

Comment: It is not that tricky, but I suspect  your document class has to do with your problem. Normally, your code was OK.

Answer (score 3):

You have error in column headers. Instead used

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{Suite} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \textbf{Workload} \\
```

it should be

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Suite}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Workload}} \\
```

(observe differences in curly braces). With above code line your MWE works fine. Anyway, I would consider @Bernard suggestion to use `\thead` (with the appropriate settings in the preamble) instead and also use `tabularx` table as follows:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

Table \ref{wrk-desc} briefly
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \makegapedcells
\caption{}\label{wrk-desc}
\label{prt-desc}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|L|}
    \hline
    \thead{Suite} & \thead{Workload} \\
    \hline
Item 1 & program1,  program2, ... \\
    \hline
Item 2 & program10, program11, ... \\
    \hline
Item 3 & program20, program21, ... \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]